# How do I design the shading ring of an induction disc relay?

Tags: relay

Can anybody guide me to any resource which gives the formulae for estimating the phaseshift caused due to a shading ring in an electromagnet? Specifically I am thinking of the shading ring in an induction disk relay.

Regards
Abhishek

Comment: Does skin effect at 60Hz enter the math?

Comment: I don't think so